# How do I have to understand the meaning of "as to" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> A Utopian society might demand that the press print nothing until it had reached absolute certainty.But such a society would be so full of rumors and lies *as to* make the errors of our journalism look like models of truth by comparison.

I heard it functions like *enough* but I cannot read this way naturally..
How do I paraphrase it?

Comment: *But a society would be so full of rumours and lies **so that** the errors of journalism…*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

> But a society would be so full of rumors and lies that it would make
>   the errors of our journalism look like models of truth by comparison.
>
> But a society would be so full of rumors and lies making the errors of
>   our journalism look like models of truth by comparison.

This is also a perfectly valid option, even though it doesn't sound natural to you for some reason:

> But a society would be so full of rumors and lies enough to make the
>   errors of our journalism look like models of truth by comparison.